IPv6 DNS server overrides IPv4 DNS
I have a windows machine which suddenly could not resolve some IP addresses which it normally has no issue with. the DNS records are hosted on cloudflare.com and one.com Iverified that the records were intact, and by SSHing into a Debian server verified that nslookup worked fine on that server...
inspecting the nslookup output, i noticed that the address of the DNS server was NOT the one I was expecting, but an IPv6 address. Experimenting a little led me to a Ubuntu box I use for k3s, which was suddenly (as in: I did not set up a DNS on it) sporting an IPv6 DNS server, and my windows PC was using that to resolve domains, instead of the configured ipv4 DNSes.
It turned out that a reconfigured router (openwrt) still had the dnsmasq set up and has decided to select my Ubuntu box as the dns server...
I have run ipconfig /flushdns arp /d * both without dhcp enabled and with, and nslookup insists on using the IPv6 dns. (I have deleted the dnsmasq service from the router, though the leases persist)

nslookup someservice.k8s.kodeninjaer.dk
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fd76:22ec:e881::1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out


How do I force nslookup to use the IPv4 DNS instead og the (now dead and gone) IPv6 ?

Maybe running ipconfig /renew will make the desired DNS server appear in ipconfig /all.

Does your Windows machine use DHCP or SLAAC on any interfaces? If so, what's the DHCP server telling it to use as a DNS server? Or in the case of SLAAC, what are the IPv6 router's router advertisements telling it to use as the DNS server? I suppose the Windows machine could also be getting a DNS config from an Active Directory domain it's connecting to, so if you've got that going on on your network, you may need to see if that's where your Windows box is getting its DNS config from.

@Spiff I use DHCP with a static lease set in the router. the openwrt device was suppose3d to be pure aCCESS POINT MODE

So look at what DNS settings the DHCP server is telling DHCP clients to use. My point is that the DNS protocol doesn't provide a way to discover DNS servers, so if your client devices are using DNS servers you didn't expect, they must have received that bad configuration some other way, such as DHCP, IPv6 "router advertisements" as part of SLAAC, or something else.
